Python threading: what is the correct way to achieve queue order preservation in the producer-consumer pattern
I have a producer that gives data regularly, then it is analysed over the network with a few workers, and the results should be processed sequentially, exactly in the order the producer gives them, not as the workers have finished the analysis.
producer -> queue1 -> worker1, ..., workern -> queue2 -> ...
I would like to know if my solution is pythonic or if there is a better way to do it.  In short, after the processing, each worker waits to put its result into the end queue until it's the right moment.
from threading import Thread, Lock
from queue import Queue
from time import sleep
from random import random

class Producer(Thread):

    def __init__(self, queue, id=1):

        super().__init__()

        self.queue = queue
        self.id = id

    def run(self, init=1, end=20):

        for n in range(init, end+1):
            item = f"item #{n}"
            self.queue.put(item)
            print(f"producer #{self.id}: {item} sent to queue")
            sleep(1)

        self.queue.put(None)

class Worker(Thread):

    lock1 = Lock()
    lock2 = Lock()

    def __init__(self, queue1, queue2, id=1):

        super().__init__()

        self.queue1 = queue1
        self.queue2 = queue2
        self.id = id

    def run(self):

        q1, q2 = self.queue1, self.queue2
        cons = f"consumer #{self.id}"

        while True:

            with self.lock1:
                item = q1.get()
                if item is None:
                    q1.put(None)
                    return
                q1.nread += 1
                n = q1.nread

            print(f"{cons}: {item} obtained [get #{n}]")
            sleep(6 * random())
            print(f"{cons}: {item} processed")

            while True:
                with self.lock2:
                    if n == q2.nwritten + 1:
                        q2.put(item)
                        q2.nwritten += 1
                        print(" " * 10 + f"-> {cons}: {item} sent to queue")
                        q1.task_done()
                        break
                sleep(.1)

q1 = Queue()
q1.nread = 0
q2 = Queue()
q2.nwritten = 0

workers = [Worker(q1, q2, id=i) for i in range(1, 5)]
producer = Producer(q1)

for worker in workers:
    worker.start()

producer.start()
producer.join()
for worker in workers:
    worker.join()


This looks very inefficient. For starters, you do a busy-loop spinning while waiting for the right moment to drop an item into the queue instead of waiting for a Condition variable. Also your workers cannot continue while waiting for one of them. Effective utilization will be low. I would replace queue 2 with a heap or priority queue with the sorting criterium being the item number. Then the consumer of queue 2 can wait until the next number is the first entry in the queue

Your code is overly complicated First of all, your main thread is doing nothing after it creates the threads except waiting for their completion. There is therefore no reason why you need a separate producer thread when the main thread can do this. Second, you can do away with the explicit queue processing you are doing by creating a multithreading pool (with 4 threads in this case). I have reduced the sleep times and removed the print statements:
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
from time import sleep, time
from random import random

def producer(init=1, end=20):
    for n in range(init, end+1):
        yield f"item #{n}"
        sleep(.1)

def worker(item):
    sleep(.3)
    return f"{item} processed"

with ThreadPool(4) as pool:  # 4 threads isn the pool
    start = time()
    results = list(pool.imap(worker, producer()))
    elapsed_time = time() - start
print(results)
print('elpased time:', elapsed_time)

Prints:
['item #1 processed', 'item #2 processed', 'item #3 processed', 'item #4 processed', 'item #5 processed', 'item #6 processed', 'item #7 processed', 'item #8 processed', 'item #9 processed', 'item #10 processed', 'item #11 processed', 'item #12 processed', 'item #13 processed', 'item #14 processed', 'item #15 processed', 'item #16 processed', 'item #17 processed', 'item #18 processed', 'item #19 processed', 'item #20 processed']
elpased time: 2.2241790294647217

Note
This is very little code but there is a lot to understand. So I suggest you read the Python manual to understand how multithreading (and multiprocessing) pools work. Specifically, we are using the multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool.imap method, which takes as arguments worker function (worker in this case) and an iterable of tasks to be submitted (a generator function in this case). The important thing to note about the imap method is that the producer generator function is producing its values to be processed by worker "lazily". That is, tasks are submitted to the pool for processing by worker as they are yielded by producer If we had used instead the map method, all 20 values would first have to be yielded by producer before anything would be submitted to the pool.

Thank you, your answer was very useful and that is exactly what I am needing.  I wonder why threading tutorials overcomplicate it.

Focussing just on the task of reordering items in a multi-producer queue:
This part of your code looks very inefficient:
            while True:
                with self.lock2:
                    if n == q2.nwritten + 1:
                        q2.put(item)
                        q2.nwritten += 1
                        print(" " * 10 + f"-> {cons}: {item} sent to queue")
                        q1.task_done()
                        break

What is happening here is that every thread that reaches this point will constantly loop, acquiring the lock and checking the content of the queue, even if there was no change in-between. This means that all threads except the one that has the next item in order will hammer that lock, waste CPU time, and do no actual work. Worse, since Python can only run one thread at a time, chances are high that the one thread that can make forward-progress cannot actually run and if it sleeps, its chance of acquiring the lock is low and only gets lower as you add more worker threads.
You need to use a design that either allows other threads to do work while waiting for the only with the next entry or go to sleep until work can continue. The first option is obviously preferable. We also want to minimize the amount of cross-thread communication, locking, unlocking, and other expensive operations.
For this, I propose using a queue that orders the elements internally and only notifies the consumer once the next entry is available. That way, worker threads can just dump their results into the queue and continue working, even if the thread with the next entry is a bit slower for some reason. Typically, such a self-ordering queue is implemented as a binary heap, also known as a priority queue, except here we need a few extra bells and whistles, so Python's PriorityQueue is not well suited. But it isn't hard to make our own.
Actually, since we know which item we want, we don't even need to build a full heap. We can simply use a dictionary. Here is a barebones version that should not be too hard to extend further.
import threading


class OrderedQueue:
    def __init__(self, maxsize=None, nextitem=0):
        self.maxsize = maxsize
        self.nextitem = nextitem
        self.lock = threading.Lock()
        self.read_avail = threading.Condition(self.lock)
        self.write_avail = threading.Condition(self.lock)
        self.items = {}

    def put(self, index, item):
        def can_put():
            # Even if the maximum size is reached, we allow inserting the next
            # output item. Otherwise we may deadlock
            return self.maxsize is None or \
                len(self.items) < self.maxsize or \
                index <= self.nextitem
        with self.lock:
            self.write_avail.wait_for(can_put)
            if index < self.nextitem:
                # notify next waiter that we did not insert
                self.write_avail.notify()
                raise ValueError("unexpected item number")
            self.items[index] = item
            if index == self.nextitem:
                self.read_avail.notify()

    def get(self):
        def can_pop():
            return self.nextitem in self.items
        with self.lock:
            self.read_avail.wait_for(can_pop)
            index = self.nextitem
            item = self.items.pop(index)
            self.nextitem += 1
            if can_pop():
                self.read_avail.notify() # next reader if any
            self.write_avail.notify()
        return index, item

As noted in the other answer, other designs are often easier and lead to the same result. Here is one alternative using future objects with a thread or process pool:
from concurrent import futures
import collections


def more_work():
    """Return True if more work is available to be scheduled"""
    return False


def do_work():
    pass

    
queue = collections.deque()
max_workers = 4
max_items_inflight = max_workers * 2
with futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=max_workers) as threadpool:
    # initialize work queue with initial batch of work items
    while len(queue) < max_items_inflight and more_work():
        queue.append(threadpool.submit(do_work))
    # retrieve results in order and add more work to thread queue
    while more_work():
        queue.append(threadpool.submit(do_work))
        oldest_future = queue.popleft()
        oldest_result = oldest_future.result()
    # drain the queue
    for oldest_future in queue:
        oldest_result = oldest_future.result()

Compared to threadpool.map(), this still works even if you don't know the number of work items a-priori, if the number is very large or potentially infinite.
